# Cannot filter specific WPF datagrid using combo box text in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, .net-4.5

My WPF app has two Tabitems and a SQLite database with a table called `studentdata` which has multiple columns.

Inside the 1st tabitem there is a datagrid named `dg1`, a combo box and a button. The 2nd tabitem currently has only a datagrid named `dg2` which should display some filtered data, for simplicity sake say, whose `PaidFeesOn` column is blank only those rows should be displayed in `dg2`. The combo box should also be filled with unique student names.

While on `dg1` upon app load should display all the data, but when an item is selected from the combo box and then the button is pressed then `dg1` should display only those data whose `Name` column value matches with the combo box selected item.

Now for filtering the datagrid using the combo box text I've done the following in the viewmodel :

```cs
public RelayCommand ComboFilterButtonClicked { get; set; }

public CollectionView ComboFilterView { get; set; }

public List<Students> _myitems;
public List<Students> MyItems
{
    get { return _myitems; }
    set { _myitems = value; }
}

public StudentsViewModel()
{
    //........

    ComboFilterButtonClicked = new RelayCommand(ComboFilterData);
    MyItems = GetStudents();
    ComboItems = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyItems);
    ComboFilterView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(SData);
                ComboFilterView.Filter = OnComboFilterTriggered;
}

public bool OnComboFilterTriggered(object item)
{
    var lookup = item as Students;

    if (lookup != null)
    {
        string x = "";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ComboText))
            return (lookup.Name == x);
    }
    return true;
}

public void ComboFilterData(object param)
{
    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyItems).Refresh();
}
```

and the XAML for the combo box :

```xml
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" Width="300"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ComboItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
        Text="{Binding ComboText,Mode=TwoWay}">
</ComboBox>
```

But when my app loads the `dg1` datagrid is blank and when I select an item from the combo box the combo box text shows texts like ``` System.Collections.Generic.List``1[filterDGs.MainWindow+Students] ``` which is due to(I believe..) `return GetStudents().ToString();` inside the `get` of `ComboText`, but what should that `get` contain ?

Note: I'm also trying to add combo box autocomplete suggestappend (like winforms) feature to the combo box.

I'm sharing the full code [here](https://codeshare.io/Lw8QRb) for better understanding and testing purposes (if anyone wished to).

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `ComboText` property in the view model with a property that holds the currently selected `Students` object:

```
private Students _selectedStudent;
public Students SelectedStudent
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedStudent;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedStudent = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedStudent));
    }
}

public bool OnComboFilterTriggered(object item)
{
    var lookup = item as Students;

    return lookup != null
        && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedStudent?.Name)
        && lookup.Name == _selectedStudent.Name;
}

public void ComboFilterData(object param)
{
    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyItems).Filter = OnComboFilterTriggered;
}
```

Bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` to this property:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" Width="300"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ComboItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudent}">
```

Comment: The selected item now shows properly but the filtering doesn't work when I hit the Filter button :(

Comment: Doesn't work? Does the `OnComboFilterTriggered` method get called? Then it's your own logic that doesn't work.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong in my logic then but I cannot figure out what ? Is there something wrongly called in the view model constructor !.  BTW, how do I replace  the part `nameof` in c# 5.0 ?

Comment: Use a string: `OnPropertyChanged("SelectedStudent");`

Comment: When I select an item from the combo box dropdown and hit the button the text from the combo box disappears(which should not happen) and the datagrid `dg1` does not get filtered by the column `Name` which is what I intend to do..

Comment: What method is being called? Did you debug your code?

Comment: The button is binded with the command `ComboFilterButtonClicked` and I think the logic inside the `if` statement of `OnComboFilterTriggered` is messed up... The idea for filter is that the datagrid should filter and show only those rows whose `Name` column matches with the combo box selected item

Comment: Yup. Look at my edited implementation of the `OnComboFilterTriggered` method.

Comment: Thank you. One additional thing (if I may ask), if I wanted to do the filtering thing live like the datagrid updates while I'm typing in the combo box, how do I do that?